# iText PDF adding image issue

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add images to a pdf report using iText, but I'm facing some issue with the scaling of the images. [iText 5.5.9]

[image]

From the above image, at the bottom right side of the pdf, the last image is scaled to be extremely small and fit to the current page. Can i know if there a way to ask iText to skip this page and go to the next page if the size doesnt match with the rest of the images?

Part of my code are as followed.

```
    PdfPTable imageTable = new PdfPTable((imageCount < maxPhotoPerRow) ? imageCount : maxPhotoPerRow); 
    imageTable.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);

    cell = new PdfPCell(imageArray.get(t),true);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cell.setPadding(1.0f);

    imageTable.addCell(cell);
```

Any help or input will be great! Thanks

----- Edit  15/12/2017 -------- 
Added the line of code "image.setScaleToFitHeight(false)", it worked. but some of the images are showing now.

[image: 2]

Anyone can help please!

Comment: Why aren't you using the latest version of iText? You should use iText 7. The problem you describe was typical for some versions in the iText 5 series. Whether or not it can be fixed depends on the version of iText you are using. Since you don't mention that version number, no one can give you an accurate answer.

Comment: The solution could be to add `image.setScaleToFitHeight(false);` but the method `setScaleToFitHeight()` was only introduced in the higher numbers of the iText 5 series. Anyway: you should consider updating to iText 7 anyway. iText 5 is no longer supported for developers who aren't a customer of iText Software.

Comment: hello, thank for the reply. I'm using iText 5.5.9. I believe this version have the method you suggested. I will try it out.

Comment: Hello, i have added the line of code "image.setScaleToFitHeight(false);", it worked somehow, but some of the images now is not showing.